# django is_active does not disable the user

Tags: django

I have a Django project that is like a blog and only a few people are using its panel. There was a user that about 5 people where using and we decided to disable this user and create separate accounts for them. In order to prevent errors in the future we decided just to disable this user and not to delete it. I did it manually using the Django's admin panel. I changed is_active to false but the user still is active and can login to the blog panel. Can you please help me find what is the reason?

Comment: Did you make a custom login view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes. I think I see your point. In our login view we should check wether the user is active or not, right?

Comment: yes, but since your question does not contain that logic, I'm afraid I can not help you with that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's alright. It's a private project and I guess I do not have the permission to share any piece of it. Thank you so much for helping me find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a custom login that does not check is_active of users. Simply I should handle it in my custom login view.